# What is the difference between using Siamese networks and MANN in one shot learning?

Tags: deep-learning, memory-networks

Memory Augmented Neural Networks have an external memory which helps to learn something with the low amount of data. It also can manipulate the memory in a dynamic manner. On another hand, siamese networks try to learn an encoding for each category and then use that encoding vector in classifying never seen examples. For face clustering in [Open-Face](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) they have used a siamese network.

What is the difference between these two approaches?

I feel siamese networks still need to trail well with a lot of data before getting a network which capable of providing generalized encodings to categories.

Please explain this.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. My usecase is "To identify and flag duplicate images in my S3 bucket with a new image coming from my android app"

Comment: Thank you for the question. I am new to these network. Do you know by any chance why we don't update the network please in case of dissimilar pairs and only update it if we have similar pairs? –